# object reference not set to an object when display location

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, view, null

I have Locations column in my site. In database there is separate tables for ,

Country
State
city
Region

These all table id's are stored into Locations table then Location Table Id is referred to LocationId in candidatedetails.

My problem is, i want to show what location candidates stored.

Eg:

Location: City, Country like that. If locationId is null means it shows

**"Object Reference not set to an object"**

So I use code like following,

```
<strong>Present Location:</strong>
        <%if (Model.LocationId.HasValue)
          { %>
            <%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).City.Name%><%:","%><%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).Country.Name%>
        <%} else { %>
                <%:Model.LocationId == null ? "" : Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).City.Name%><%:","%><%:Model.GetLocation(Model.LocationId.Value).Country.Name%>
        <%} %>
```

**In Repository:**

```
public Location GetLocation(int locationId)
    {
        return _db.Locations.SingleOrDefault(l=>l.Id==locationId);
    }
```

But still i get error on the above code...Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

`SingleOrDefault` will return `null` for "default" for classes when no match is found, so even checking `LocationId` is illegal as `Model` will be the result, `null` - therefore, you will need to do a null check on your Model. If it's *something* and not *nothing* then it's a location instance.

Comment: Is there any way to check null in html page itself?

Comment: `<%if (Model != null) ...`

Comment: Then it's possible something else is null even after retrieving a location, such as `City`.